# List Category Posts plugin upgrade fails with fatal error

Tags: errors, upgrade, plugin-list-category-post

I just tried an automatic upgrade of [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) plugin to version 0.17.2 on WordPress 3.0.5. I think I had 0.17.1 before. It installed but failed to activate:

```
Plugin could not be activated because it triggered a fatal error.
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_OLD_FUNCTION or T_FUNCTION or T_VAR or '}' in /hsphere/local/home/carrollp/clanecommunity.ie/wp-content/plugins/list-category-posts/include/CatListDisplayer.php on line 10
```

If I understand correctly author has [requested](http://picandocodigo.net/programacion/wordpress/list-category-posts-wordpress-plugin-english/) issues be posted here.

I've never debugged WordPress before. Appreciate any help. My site home page is relying on this plugin. Thanks!

Comment: Had same problem with the update. It does not work with PHP 4. Reverting to 0.16 fixed problem, but you might consider supporting PHP4 in the new version.

Comment: PHP4 support will phase out after the next release of WordPress (3.1), so this could be a good opportunity to upgrade to PHP5 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I've asked for issues to be reported here, so that you can get answers from the larger community of WordPress users and developers at WordPress Answers.

Regarding the issue, other user also reported it, and it is due to the webhost using PHP 4. Line 10 of CatListDisplayer.php declares a private attribute. PHP 4 doesn't have public, private or protected accessors.

Is there a way to ask your webhosting provider to update your server to PHP 5?

The other possible solution is to download the previous version of the plugin: 0.16, which doesn't use Object Oriented PHP.

Comment: Hola Fernando. I can ask, but it may be several days before I get a response - and that might be "No" :). In the meantime I guess it is time for me to learn how to manually install plugins. I see I can get previous versions on WordPress.org. Do you expect 0.17.1 would work, or should I go back older. Gracias!

Comment: Ah. I just see your updated answer. Perfect. Will try that.

Comment: Hola jmkie! You should install version 0.16.1. Manually installing a plugin is pretty easy. Just download the zip file on: http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/list-category-posts.0.16.1.zip. FTP into your host, and go into yourblog/wp-content/plugins/. There should be a list-category-posts folder there, just delete it. Then  unzip the "list-category-posts" folder from the zip file you downloaded, and upload it to yourblog/wp-content/plugins.

Comment: You can find more info on manually installing plugins on this link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Managing_Plugins#Manual_Plugin_Installation

Comment: 0.16.1 Working fine again. Many thanks for the speedy and detailed response.

Comment: Great! Hope you can get PHP upgraded to PHP5 on your host. If this answered your question, you can mark it as answered. And please, do stick around for further WordPress questions, this site has a great growing commmunity!